# .NET: Where is the default implementation for "==" op_Equality() for value types?

Tags: .net, operator-overloading

I was poking around in .NET Reflector, and noticed that for reference types like "String" for example, there is an explicit overload of the "==" operator:

```
typeof(string).GetMethod("op_Equality", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

returns: System.Reflection.MethodInfo for the "==" operator.

Due to its implementation, you can't do things like:

```
if("hi" == 3)  // compiler error, plus code would throw an exception even if it ran)
```

However, the same thing works for value types:

```
if((int)1 == (float)1.0)  // correctly returns true
if((int)1 == (float)1.2)  // correctly returns false
```

I'm trying to figure out exactly how .NET internally handles the type conversion process, so I was looking for the implementation of op_Equality() in .NET Reflector, but "int" doesn't have one.

```
typeof(int).GetMethod("op_Equality", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

returns null.

So, where is the default implementation for the "==" operator for value types?
I'd like to be able to call it via reflection:

```
public bool AreEqual(object x, object y)
{
    if(x.GetType().IsValueType && y.GetType().IsValueType)
        return x == y; // Incorrect, this calls the "object" equality override
    else
        ...
}
```

---

Edit #1:

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
(int)1 == (float)1;                          // returns true
System.ValueType.Equals( (int)1, (float)1 ); // returns false
```

---

Edit #2:

Also tried this, but no love:

```
object x = (int)1;
object y = (float)1.0;

bool b1 = (x == y);                 // b1 = false
bool b2 = ((ValueType)x).Equals(y); // b2 = false
```

I beleive this .Equals operator on ValueType does not work due to this type check (ripped from .NET Reflector):

```
ValueType.Equals(object obj)
{
    ...

    RuntimeType type = (RuntimeType) base.GetType();
    RuntimeType type2 = (RuntimeType) obj.GetType();
    if (type2 != type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the evaluation of (int)1 == (float)1.0 doesn't rely on any special == operator, just the conversion rules.

The compiler will turn this into  (float)((int)1) == (float)1.0

Edit:
The rules are specified [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx).

Comment: Thats getting on the right track. Is there a way to tell what the proper cast should be? For example how does it know to cast the result to float instead of int? there has to be an order of precedence somewhere...

Comment: This is correct. If you code C# (int)1 == (float)1.0; The compiler will generate the IL equivalent of (float)1.0 == (float)1.0; It upcasts the int at compile time, so at runtime the types are equal.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [ValueType.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx)

In many cases this just does a bit by bit comparison of the values.  In certain cases though it will use reflection to verify the fields.

**EDIT**

You're confusing how C# compares value types and how .Net compares value types.  ValueType.Equals is a function in .Net used to compare value type objects which have the same type.  C# will emit code that eventually calls that function.  But it does not call it with an "int" and a "float".  Instead it first converts both of them to a type which does not loose precision for either value (double) and then compares the resulting double values.  This is why you see a difference in behavior.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work as expected. ValueType.Equals((int)1, (float)1); returns false, the opposite of: (int)1 == (float)1;

Comment: @rally25rs, the code you wrote shoudln't compile AFAICT.  ValueType.Equals is an instance method and only takes 1 parameter

Comment: I just noticed there is a ValueType.Equals(object, object) that is inherited from Object, and a ValueType.Equals(object) that is on ValueType. I was calling the wrong one. oops! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the default implementation for `==` `op_Equality` for value types?

There is no default `==` for value types. Try writing your own value type

```
struct JustAnotherValueType
{
  public readonly int Field;
  public JustAnotherValueType(int f) { Field = f; }
}
```

Make two values `x` and `y` of your type. Try saying `x == y` with them. It will not compile. You **can** say

```
(object)x == (object)y
```

but that will perform boxing on `x` (let's call it box 1) and boxing on `y` (box 2) and then perform a reference comparison on the two boxes. Hence it will always return false. And therefore it's useless, and that's the reason why the overload `==(object x, object y)` is not automatically selected when you use `==` between two `JustAnotherValueType`.

So what's going on with `int` and `float`? You can compare them with `==` in C#, and they don't have the `op_Equality` method?! The explanation is that these overloads are defined by **[the C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)**. See the sections *Integer comparison operators* and *Floating-point comparison operators*.

So the fact is that while these operators do not exist as members of the .NET structs, the C# Language Specification defines them, and the C# compiler must produce some valid IL to mimic their behavior.

By the way, `System.Object` does not have an `op_Equality` either. It too is only defined by C#. See the section *Reference type equality operators*. Note that `System.Object` has a `ReferenceEquals` method that the compiler might choose to translate this overload of `==` into. Also note that this section of the spec gives limitations so that `x == y` will never perform boxing on `x` or `y`.

What about value types like `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, and `Guid` that are not mentioned in the C# Specification, but for which it is legal to use `==`? The answer is, these **do** have the `op_Equality` member.

Conclusion: The C# Language Specification defines a lot of `==` overloads that an implementation of C# is required to have, and some of these overloads involve `int` and `float` and `object`.

Remark: The virtual instance method `Equals(object)` is defined in `object` and inherited by all value types. For structs that don't override this method themselves, the `override` in `System.ValueType` is used. It compares by value. So with `x` and `y` like above, `x.Equals(y)` will work fine. `Equals` is a virtual instance method. On the other hand `==` is a `static` "method" for which overload resolution based on the compile-time types of the two operands is performed (no "virtual dispatch").

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for [ValueType.Equals(object obj)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx) which is inherited to your structs. It uses reflection to compare all fields.

Comment: This is the a-typical case.  Much more commonly it will do a bit by bit comparison

Answer (score 1):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384294/where-is-the-implementation-of-internalequalsobject-obja-object-objb/384296#384296) to another question provides the Rotor implementation. The actual code is implemented in the CLR as native code.

Specifically:

```
// Compare the contents (size - vtable - sink block index).
BOOL ret = memcmp(
    (void *) (pThisRef+1), 
    (void *) (pCompareRef+1), 
    pThisRef->GetMethodTable()->GetBaseSize() - sizeof(Object) - sizeof(int)) == 0;
```