# What is a better way to check that a given object is a particular value type?

Tags: c#, il, value-type, gettype

Below are the 2 commonly used approaches to check before unbox.

```
myObject.GetType() == typeof(MyValueType)

IL_0001:  callvirt    System.Object.GetType
IL_0006:  ldtoken     UserQuery.MyValueType
IL_000B:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_0010:  call        System.Type.op_Equality


myObject is MyValueType

IL_0001:  isinst      UserQuery.MyValueType
```

Plus, I am wondering why C# calls `System.Type.op_Equality` instead of `ceq` Isn't that reference equality check?

#### Update

Actually, there is a 3rd way. (from C# 5.0 in a Nutshell)

```
MyValueType? x = myObject as MyValueType?;
```

Then check `x.HasValue` and use `x.Value`

Which one of the 3 would you use?

Comment: Flip a three-sided coin?

Comment: Which one would I use? Certainly `myObject is MyValueType`. That's what the `is` keyword is there for. I have faith that the compiler will choose a gode translation of it. Side note: With a value type, the two forms give the same result. But in other cases there's a difference, of course. For example `myObject is IDisposable` works fine while `myObject.GetType()` could never give an interface type or an abstract class. Another example, `myObject is Func<object>` will give true for a `Func<string>` even if the type `Func<>` is a sealed type. Covariance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering why C# calls `System.Type.op_Equality` instead of `ceq`.

Because types are compared by value, not by reference. There could be two type objects in memory that refer to the same type.

> Which one of the three would you use?

If you want to know whether an instance is of a particular type, there is an operator **specifically designed to solve that problem and that problem alone**: `is`. Why would you ever *not* use the tool that was specifically designed to solve your problem? If you're replacing a roof and you have a choice between a roofing hatchet and a hammer, I hope you would use the roofing hatchet.

Now, if you need to both do a type test *and obtain the value* then I would be inclined to use `as` because that is the operator **specifically designed to solve that problem**.

Comment: I thought that `is` is designed to solve if an instance is "compatible" with a given type, whereas `GetType()` is for that the types are actually identical. In this case since the type is sealed so the 2 give the same result. However, I felt that `is` is a bit of overuse.

Comment: By using `as` I must also bring in `Nullable`, wouldn't that be a bit overuse as well? Does it weight cheaper than `is` + unboxing ?

Comment: From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx " Type object that represents a type is unique; that is, two Type object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of Type objects using reference equality" So it says reference equality

Comment: @colinfang: Your question was not which is *cheaper*, your question was *which one would you use*?  I answered the question you asked. If you want to know the answer to which one is cheaper: **write the code both ways, run it both ways, measure the expense, and then you'll know which one is cheaper.**

Comment: @colinfang: Type objects provided by the CLR guarantee reference equality. Remember, `Type` is unsealed; if you want to create your own `Type` objects, you are not required to enforce reference equality (though doing so is a good idea.)  Therefore the C# compiler does not attempt to optimize equality operations on types down to reference equality; the `op_Equality` method will check for reference equality.

Comment: Note that it is highly unlikely that the performance of this operation will be of relevance in your benchmarks.  Presumably other code will run in response to determining the type of your object, and that code will almost always be more expensive than answering the type question.

Answer (score 0):

If an overloaded `==` operator exists it is being preferred. If not, what would be the point of it?

Besides of doing the measurement to find out what is faster, I think the type equality check will be faster because the JIT contains a special optimization that recognizes this pattern and optimizes it to the fullest. On the other hand, maybe the `isinst` will be compiled to the same instructions if the JIT recognizes that you are casting to a value type (which cannot possibly have subtypes).

Your 3rd method of checking cannot beat the 2nd because you are requiring the JIT to do more than before. At best this optimized back into the 2nd form, but I would be surprised to see that given the poor optimization capabilities of the current JIT.